# Move all divs with specific class to container

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic

How can I make jquery put all of the divs with specific class into a container? I would like to have a function, that would move divs dynamically. So that when a div gets the new class, it automatically gets moved to this container.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move them:

```
$("#yourContainer").append( $("div.yourClass") );
```

Or perhaps, to avoid touching ones already in the container:

```
$("#yourContainer").append($("div.yourClass").not("#yourContainer div.yourClass"));
```

For elements that already exist in the DOM the `.append()` method moves them to the new parent that you specify.

I'm not aware of an event that is triggered by a change in class, so I'm not sure what to suggest as far as having it happen automatically.

Comment: what about something like: `$('.yourDiv').addClass('newClass').change();` to trigger the change event when the class is added, and then do whatever he needs to do inside the change event handler. I'm like 50% sure that can work